# Overlap columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have one row inside which I have three columns like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I would like the three columns to overlap and create and illusion like the the following:

[image]

Where each bottle will represent each of the image that I have in the code snippet above.

Thanks for any help

**Note** The image in the middle should appear to be in the front and bigger than the other two images in the back (exactly as shown in the picture)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overlap all the time, instead of using grid you could use negative margins instead:

```css
.bottle {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bottles .bottle:first-child {
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.bottles .bottle:last-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottles">
  <img class="bottle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620">
  <img class="bottle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620">
  <img class="bottle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620">
</div>
```

I resized images to fit inside snippet preview, but you will need only to play with negative margins to achieve effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for from what I understood. I created a new class for each column and shifted it using the margins. You can adjust the margin % to fit your desired position.

```
<style>
.a1 {
    margin-left: 15%;
    position: absolute;
}
.a2 {
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
.a3 {
    margin-left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 a1">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 a2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 a3">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following:

```css
.col-4 {
  position: relative;
}

.col-4:nth-child(1), .col-4:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.col-4:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 -40px 0 -40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 321px;
  height: 620px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/21/23/29/fog-3622519_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/08/27/14/19/evening-55067_960_720.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/07/15/51/woman-591576_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Why the specific height and width for the images?

Comment: Also I tried this there are two issues: 1- It's not responsive, 2- The image in the middle does not appear to be bigger than the others

Comment: @user765368 these were the dimensions that you specified. Well I guess you do know that SO doesn't always provide a copy paste answer and that you have to tweak an answer for your needs

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using "col-4" use "col-sm-4" or here is the rule for column [click](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x620" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This is what the OP already has. The OP want's the other divs to be overlapped by the center div