# how can i overlap two elements using twitter-bootstrap (v4.4.0 or higher)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlap

There used to be two classes in bootstrap that allowed one to push and pull elements.
If used correctly it was possible to overlap two elements.
example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color:green">column 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-md-3" style="background-color:blue">column 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap has replaced these functionalities with the "order" class.
However this does not behave in the same way push and pull behaves. 
As a result it's not possible to make elements overlap using the "order" class.

In the example piece of code you can find the class pull-md-3. This would cause "column 2" to be pulled to the left by three steps(in the grid system), thus causing it to overlap "column 1".

Of course this can still be done using plain old css. 
I am just hoping that there is still a way to do this using bootstrap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009312/overlap-columns-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: Hhmmm..there doesn't seem to be a bootstrap utility for this. Not surprising given the nature of flexbox. Simple enough with CSS-Grid which is likely where BS5 will go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile classes like "pull-md-" by recompiling CSS using SASS or LESS. It will be quite troublesome to arrange one by one.

Bootstrap 4 uses flex. Compared to older versions, there are now only offset classes. `Offset` auxiliary classes; uses the **margin-left** property that takes a percentage value.

The best solution would be to change the **margin-left** value to a negative percentage.

According to Bootstrap 4, you will need to change the offset-md-3 class to `margin-left: -25%;` pull to make `margin-left: 25%;` pull-md-3.

Comment: Thank you. 
I guess the amount of css to write to achieve what i want is so little it doesn't really matter wether i can use bootstrap or not ..